# Tax Rates and Income

Tags: statistics

I have a 5000-individual dataset and their incomes vary from 0 to 5000. For each band of income, following tax-rates are applicable:

If income$ >4000, t=0.6$

If $3000<$ income $<4000, t=0.5$

If $2000<$ income $<3000, t=0.4$

If $1000<$ income $<2000, t=0.3$

For all income $< 1000, t=0$

The mean of total tax collected is added to after-tax income (i.e $\text{income}-(\text{income}\times\text{tax rate})$) for every individual and this process is iterated over several periods.

-Can a general equation be formulated to predict the number of iterations required till all incomes are equal?

-Can a STATA code be written to run a simulation for this process?

Thanks!

Comment: The incomes are not guaranteed to ever become equal. For example, suppose there are only two persons earning different incomes, both below 1000.

Comment: The dataset is for 5000 people and I have randomized incomes using runiform() in STATA.

Comment: The incomes will almost never become exactly equal.

Comment: Can this be rigorously proved?

Comment: Yes this shouldn't be too difficult. Hint: what has to happen for 2 people to end up with the same income after one round?

Comment: Are the tax rates supposed to be **marginal** tax rates?